# ElasticSearch Error: Invalid term-aggregator order path [_key]. Unknown aggregation [_key] while performing aggregation from Java

Tags: java, elasticsearch, aws-elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

i'm getting the below error when performing aggregation
Error: Invalid term-aggregator order path [_key]. Unknown aggregation [_key] while performing aggregation from Java

**code**:

```
 public static void main(String[] args){

 JestClient jestClient = getJestClient();

 SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
 searchSourceBuilder.size(100);
 searchSourceBuilder.aggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("products").field("myField.keyword").
 valueType(ValueType.STRING).size(100));

 SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest(); 
 searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
 Search searchQuery = new Search.Builder(searchSourceBuilder.toString()).
setParameter(Parameters.SCROLL,"5m").setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH).build();
JestResult hits = jestClient.execute(searchQuery);
System.out.println(hits.getJsonObject);
}

public static void getJestClient(){
JestClientFactory factory = new JestClientFactory();
        factory.setHttpClientConfig(
                new HttpClientConfig.Builder(hostname)
                        .multiThreaded(true)
                        .readTimeout(30000)
                        .build());
        return factory.getObject()
}
```

**Error**:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"aggregation_execution_exception","reason":"Invalid term- 
aggregator order path [_key]. Unknown aggregation [ . 
  _key]"}],"type":"search_phase_execution_exception","reason":"all shards 
 failed","phase":"dfs_query","grouped":true,"failed_shards": 
[{"shard":0,"index":".kibana","node":"RwVYV0S-SVmiqfMuihkcHA","reason": 
{"type":"aggregation_execution_exception","reason":"Invalid term-aggregator order path 
 [_key]. Unknown aggregation [_key]"}}]},"status":500}
```

*when I run from curl i'm getting the **output sucessfully**.*

**Curl**:

```
curl -v -X GET "https://hostname/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d 
'{"aggs" : { "products" : { 
   "terms" : {"field" : "myField.keyword","size" : 5}
}}}'
```

Not sure what is the mistake whether it is the issue with the ElasticSearch java package or i'm doing some mistake.

I'm using `Jest-5.x` and `elasticsearch 7.4.2`

Please suggest other alternatives

Answer (score 0):

ElasticSearch must 5.X
Then the problem will slove

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem
The problem is the incompatibility of Elasticsearch library 5 and 6 and above.
Problems like 'auto_generate_synonyms_phrase_query' and '_key' and '_doc'.
Elasticsearch version 7 library does not support Elasticsearch version 5.
You must version org.elasticsearch :

```
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
          <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
          <version>7.*.*</version>
      </dependency>
```

Change to versions 5:

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>5.*.*</version>
      </dependency>
```